# What Physical Quantity has SI Unit $kg \cdot m$,?

Tags: soft-question, units, si-units

What is the physical quantity that has SI (System International) unit of $kg \cdot m$ (kilogram meters)?

Comment: Sometimes torque is specified in kilogram-meter meaning the weight of 1 kilogram mass at one meter lever. Assumes standard gravity of $g=9.80665 \rm m/s^2$

Answer (score 0):

First moment of a mass distribution.

Answer (score 0):

A simple googling (takes barely 30 secs max.) can tell you the answer. Moment is something that has the "distance" along with it. Hence, *moment of* mass is $\mathrm{m\times kg}$. If you require another moment, $\mathrm{m^2\times kg}$. Probably, these first & second moments are engineering parameters.

Whatever, it's simply the *first moment of mass*..!